# Proof that the extended complex plane is compact (without using sequences)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Denote the complex plane by C

Denote the unit sphere centred at the origin by P (edited: i.e. the Riemann sphere)

Lemma: Let A$\subset$C and B$\subset$P with B corresponding to the points in A. Then A is open relative to C if and only if B is open relative to P.

Let {$Q_i$} be an open cover of C. Then there exists {$K_i$}, an open cover of P, with each $Q_j$ corresponding to a different $K_j$

P is compact by the Heine Borel theorem, so for {$K_i$}, there exists a finite subcover. Denote this finite subcover by $K_1$,...,$K_n$ (each $K_j$ is an open set, by lemma)

Then the corresponding $Q_1$,...,$Q_n$ form a finite subcover of {$Q_i$} for C. Hence C is compact.

---

is this proof valid or am i missing something?

Comment: Is $P$ a subset of $\mathbb C$? Your proof is very unclear...

Comment: P is the Riemann sphere

Comment: Is the extended plane just the one point compactification of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: yes i believe that's what it is

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch:

$1):\ $Fix the symbol $\infty $ and consider $C_{\infty}=\mathbb C\cup \left \{ \infty \right \}$.

$2):\ $Define a toplogy $\mathcal T$ on $C_{\infty}$ by declaring the open sets to be either $U$ whenever $U$ is open in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C\cup \left \{ \infty \right \}\setminus K$ whenever $K$ is a compact set in $\mathbb C$.

The topology thus defined using the "point at infinity" $\infty $, gives $C_{\infty}$ the evident geometric interpretation.

You can show easily that $\mathcal T$ is indeed a topology on $\mathbb C_\infty$ and it is not much harder to show that  $\mathbb C_\infty$ is compact.

This construction is a general one: given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, we can always construct such a compact space $Y=X\cup \left \{ * \right \}$.

Comment: what is $\infty \setminus K$ ?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\{Q_i\}$ be an open cover of C. Then there exists $\{K_i\}$, an open cover of P, with each $Q_j$ corresponding to a different $K_j$

Mistake. $Q_i$ are all subsets of $\mathbb C$, therefore none of them contains $\infty$. So $K_j$ is not an open cover of $P$.

Comment: what if i argue the other way around: Let \{$K_i$\} be an open cover of P. Then there exists \{$Q_i$\}, an open cover of C, with each $K_j$ corresponding to a different $Q_j$

Comment: @Somedude No, because some of the sets $K_i$ contain $\infty$, and you did not explain how $Q_i$ are then formed, since they cannot contain $\infty$.

Comment: I see. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: @somedude Drop the Riemann sphere enitrely. Remember what the definition of the extended complex plane is. Restart the proof.