# Show that the extended complex plane is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a subset of the extended complex plane (also known as the Riemann sphere see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)), which we will denote as $(X, d)$ henceforth. Let $V \subset S$ denote the set of points which correspond to points $G \subset X$. Show that $V$ is open relative to $S$ iff $G$ is open relative to $X$. Now, conclude that the extended complex plane is compact.

I normally include some of my own thoughts on problems when posting. However, I have made very little progress aside from showing that the unit sphere (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$), is itself compact.

Note: I have indeed looked at this [previous Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488348/proof-that-the-extended-complex-plane-is-compact-without-using-sequences) and have not reached an understanding. I believe the answer is given via some topological definitions which I have not yet encountered. The context of this question is in a real analysis course corresponding to roughly the first half of Rudin.

Comment: For the first part, note that if $V\subset S$ but the points in $V$ correspond to the points in $G$, then $V=S\cap G$. But we know that $V\subset S$ open relative to $S$ iff $V=S\cap G$ for some $G\subset X$ open relative so $X$, so ...

Comment: @Bihc Any chance you can elaborate and provide a full answer? Would be appreciated and I would be able to accept it rather than upvoting this comment.

Comment: I'm still mulling over how to prove $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is compact, so I probably shouldn't provide a full answer yet. To eloborate on what I said above, if you're reading Rudin I'm using the result of thm 2.30 and applying it here. Does that help?

Comment: @Bich I will look over it soon. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my comments above are certainly incorrect. $V\neq S\cap G$ because $S$ is the representation of the points in $G$, not the points themselves.

However, suppose that $S$ relative to $Y$ and $G$ closed relative to $X$. Then $G$ contains all its limit points. Let $p\in G$ be such a point. Then the representation of $p$ on the Riemann sphere is not in $V$. But this is a contradiction since by definition $V$ corresponds to all the points in $G$. Conversely, suppose $G$ open and $S$ closed. If $q$ is a limit point of $S$, then its representative on the plane is not in $G$, which is again a contradiction.

Now, let $\mathcal{R}=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3:|\vec{x}|=1\}$ be the Riemann Sphere which is compact under the usual metric (I'll leave this proof up to you). So $\mathcal{R}$ has finite subcover, say $\bigcup_\alpha^n V_\alpha$. But by definition each $V_i$ corresponds to the set $G_i$ on the plane, where $G_i$ is open, so it follows that $\bigcup_\alpha^n G_\alpha$ is a finite subcover for $\mathbb{\hat{C}}$. (Convince yourself that if there were points left out, this would lead to a contradiction).

Comment: This is great, +1. One question: can you prove the converse of the second paragraph? This has been a big hurdle for me.

Comment: @MathMajor, better?

Comment: Thank you. So you know, this problem has been attempted by me for some days now. You've been a great help.